# cakephp URL get rid of /app/webroot

Tags: cakephp

I have a application and I want to integrated it into my CakePhp website. I put it into webroot folder. I tried to open it in browser via

```
                 http//mywebsite.com/appname
```

but it failed. Instead, I need to reach it via

```
                 http//mywebsite.com/app/webroot/appname.
```

And will be redirect to

```
                http//mywebsite.com/app/webroot/appname/index.
```

Anyone know how to get rid of the /app/webroot string in my url? I do check the cake routing documentation but feels like didn't found a solution there.

Comment: it's probably an Apache mod-rewrite problem. Check your .htaccess file(s) in your app, and your httpd.conf file in your Apache installation

Comment: Why did you place your app in webroot? Isn't that usually used for static files (CSS/JS/images, etc)?

Comment: what version of cake are you using? your app directory should not be in webroot, your webroot should be a subdir of your app dir.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache virtual host is not configured right.

Your Document Root needs to point to the webroot dir:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /mydir/somthing/cake/app/webroot
ServerName mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then this will work:

```
http//mywebsite.com/appname
```